# HTML <meta> not validating

Tags: css, html

My HTML is not validating because of the following error:

```
Error: Attribute name not allowed on element meta at this point.
Error: Attribute content not allowed on element meta at this point.
```

HTML

```
<head>
    <title>Homepage</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
</head>
```

I have tried searching online, but can't really find an issue with the above syntax- any ideas?

Comment: what is your doctype?

Comment: How about `<meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`?

Comment: @Dekel <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: @domsson this works thanks =]

Comment: Can you post your complete html?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the doctype tag and declared the encoding in a wrong way.
I've searched the docs to help you understand what you did wrong.
Correct code underneath.

***Doctype***

> 2.2. The DOCTYPE
>
> The HTML syntax of HTML5 requires a DOCTYPE to be specified to ensure that the browser renders the page in standards mode. The DOCTYPE has no other purpose and is therefore optional for XML. Documents with an XML media type are always handled in standards mode. [DOCTYPE]
>
> The DOCTYPE declaration is  and is case-insensitive in the HTML syntax. DOCTYPEs from earlier versions of HTML were longer because the HTML language was SGML-based and therefore required a reference to a DTD. With HTML5 this is no longer the case and the DOCTYPE is only needed to enable standards mode for documents written using the HTML syntax. Browsers already do this for .

**Source:** 
[Why to use Doctype](https://html-differences.whatwg.org/#doctype)

***Character encodings***

> Always declare the encoding of your document using a meta element with a charset attribute, or using the http-equiv and content attributes (called a pragma directive). The declaration should fit completely within the first 1024 bytes at the start of the file, so it's best to put it immediately after the opening head tag.

Source: [Declaring character encodings in HTML](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations)

***Meta tags***

> The width property controls the size of the viewport. It can be set to a specific number of pixels like width=600 or to the special value device-width which is the width of the screen in CSS pixels at a scale of 100%. (There are corresponding height and device-height values, which may be useful for pages with elements that change size or position based on the viewport height.)
>
> The initial-scale property controls the zoom level when the page is first loaded. The maximum-scale, minimum-scale, and user-scalable properties control how users are allowed to zoom the page in or out.

**Source:** 
[Viewport Meta Tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

This will work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Homepage</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
</head>
```